# Discrete math help - Index Sets Union and Intersections

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I've attached part of the problem I am stuck on - I'm really just not sure where to start. Do I plug in the numbers of the interval, find the sets, and determine the union or intersection from that?

Comment: $\bigcap_{n=1}^{3}A_{n} = A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3}$, more generally, $\bigcap_{n=1}^{m}A_{n} = A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap A_{3} \cap \cdots \cap A_{m}$

Comment: What role did the {n-1, n, n^3} play in that?

Comment: $A_n$ is not an interval but a set with 3 elements. Well, you simply exchange the $n$ with the index of $A$.

Comment: Ah. Is that what the n=1, 3 is referring to?

Comment: Yes, for example $A_1\space=\space$ {$0,1,1$}

Comment: Okay, got it. So, if A2={1,2,8} and A3={2,3,27}, would the intersection be the empty set?

Comment: Correct. @lortick

Comment: Okay. Would changing the 3 to infinity change that intersection? Or would it still be disjoint? (I'm assuming the U in this case would (1, infinity).)

Comment: Actually, the intersection of {1,2,8} and {2,3,27} is {2}, not the empty set

Comment: True. I should have specified that I was including A1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, $A_1, A_2,$ and $A_3$ are sets, not intervals.  Yes, find the sets and determine the union or intersection from there.
$A_1 = ${$0,1$}, $A_2=${$1,2,8$}, and $A_3=${$2,3,27$}.   The intersection of these three sets is empty; no element is in all three.  The union of these three sets is {$0,1,2,3,8,27$}.